# Display Inline-Block with Widths as Percent

Tags: width, css

I'm trying to put 2 sections beside each other using `inline-block` and widths as a percentage, but it's not filling up the entire width of my window.

What I have so far:

HTML

```
<section class="left-content">
    "Some Code"
</section>
<section class="main-content">
    "Some More Code"
</section>
```

CSS

```
.left-content, .right-content { 
    width: 15%; 
    min-width: 150px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    vertical-align: top; 
}
.main-content { 
    width: 85%; 
    min-width: 712px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    vertical-align: top; 
}
```

But unless I work out the exact percentage down to a decimal point on my screen it doesn't work. Does anyone know of a way to do this using `inline-block` or do I have to use `float`?

Comment: I've found it's usually because there's a physical space in between the elements. You can either remove any space between elements in the markup, or set `font-size: 0` on the parent, and then restore the font in the elements themselves.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is due to the white-space and line break in your HTML markup which causes this issue. There are two options to resolve the "problem":
1. remove the line breaks and white-space from your code
2. set the `font-size` of the parent element to '0'

Additionally have you set `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a pain that I have to reset the font size. :)

Comment: Yes ;-) but there is no method without any drawbacks. The alternative using 'floats' isn't any better ...! You have the choice between the lesser of two evils.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but why not just delete the whitespace in the html. In his case: [code]...</section><section class="main-content">...[more code]

Comment: @JoshuaGoossen It is option 1, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: Parent element's ```font-size: 0;``` along with ```box-sizing: border-box;``` is the way to go.