# nested <div> with percentage width and inline-block display, overflows the screen

Tags: html, css, width

similar questions is asked several times but my question is more general!

- ### **FIRST**:

for this first question I found an accurate answer here: 
[Display Inline-Block with Widths as Percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933611/display-inline-block-with-widths-as-percent)

assume that we have a `<div>` element in an html file and add a few styles to it;

notice that the **width is 100%** and it should place all over the screen width and **shouldn't** go out of the screen

(**in this snippet the border of the element goes over the screen at the right side!**):

```css
body{
margin:0;
}
#section1{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: red 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
  hello
</div>
```

but, by the answer I found,

if I add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the css file, the view of the `<div>` element is going to be alright! and this is ok.

(run this snippeet to see the result):

```css
#section1{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: red 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
  hello
</div>
```

---

I didn't have any problems so far, that was only an introduction to understand my second question:

- ### **SECOND**

> the aforesaid words doesn't work if we have nested `<div>` elements!

I searched a lot but it wasn't effective for my example!

and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848284/aligning-nested-div-elements-with-inline-block) is partly answered this question but not much effective!

**this is the result that I want**: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spwDR.png)

**this snippet is my sample** that the two "hello" lines doesn't take place along eachother!:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.section2{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  border: green 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="section2">
  <div id="section2-1" class="section2"> hello</div>
  <div id="section2-2" class="section2">hello</div>
</div>
```

> what is the easiest way without changing the display property or adding negative margins?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem comes from the white space next to the elements, which is produced automatically when you use `display: inline-block;`

a trick is to remove white spaces as you also have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848284/aligning-nested-div-elements-with-inline-block).

if you don't want change the display property and don't remove indentation of your code (white spaces):

> the **easiest** way is to add this properties:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
```

[more](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) about `box-sizing` property

[more](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) about `float` property

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section1{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: red 5px solid;
}

#section2{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: blue 3px solid;
}
.section2{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  border: yellow 5px solid;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
  hello
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="section2">
  <div id="section2-1" class="section2"> hello</div>
  <div id="section2-2" class="section2">hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.section2{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  border: green 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="section2">
  <div id="section2-1" class="section2"> hello</div
  ><div id="section2-2" class="section2">hello</div>
</div>
```

it is working, but what did i do ? i simply tested with 40%, saw there was a space inbetween your two divs, so just deleted the space (actually a new line with some tabulations)

Comment: thanks that is good, but i don't want remove the indents in my code!

Comment: I was just pointing where the problem was, you have a lot of options like putting the `</div` on one line end, and `><div>` on the other line starts, some may think it's dirty, but actually that's easier if you tend to forget the `clear:both` after the `float` elements. if it's two elements, this method will not even be visible, ant will not require extra styling :)

Answer (score 0):

Inline-block element are `white-space dependent` and you could refer this answer to learn more about the difference between [display as block, inline and inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block). There are many ways to remove this `white-spacing`, from which one is adding `font-size 0` to `parent` div which is here `#section2` then manually you could assign `font-size` to their child element.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#section2{
  font-size:0;
}
.section2{
  font-size:18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="section2">
  <div id="section2-1" class="section2"> hello</div>
  <div id="section2-2" class="section2">hello</div>
</div>
```